# JS Extract data from string

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

So I have the following string:

```
_string = 'From 00:00 To 01:23';
```

And I need to get the times in a format that I can work with, in order to save the data.

So I was thinking if I can get something like `_string['from']` and `_string['to']` and this way I can get the values and save them in the database.

So far I have tried `.replace` but I guess I don't have enough experience in JS in order to achieve what I'm looking for.

So this is what I have tried, I can get the `To` value, but didn't had any luck with `from`:

```
_string = 'From 00: 00 To 01:23';

res = _string.replace('From ','');
res2 = res.replace('To ','');

_one = _string.split('From ');
_two = _string.split('To');
console.log(_two[1]); //OUTPUS " 01:23"
```

Expected values: `00:00 for the From value and 01:23 for the TO value`.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: 00:00 for the From value and 01:23 for the TO value

Comment: Is your data always going to be in exactly that format? Because it's a little weird that the first time value has a space after the colon.

Comment: Yes only the values for the times will be different

Comment: I believe the space in `00: 00` was an error. I've edited. It's supposed to be `00:00` right?

Comment: No, the space is always there, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\s+/g` to replace all space characters with empty string, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+:\d+/g` to match one or more digits followed by colon character followed by one or more digits

```js
var _string = 'From 00: 00 To 01:23';
var [from, to] = _string.replace(/\s+/g, "").match(/\d+:\d+/g);

console.log(from, to);
```

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting on the empty space  character.

```js
var _string = "From 00:00 To 01:23";
var res = _string.split(' ');

// res == ['From', '00:00', 'To', '01:23'];

var outputFrom = res[1]; // 00:00
var outputTo = res[3]; // 01:23

console.log(outputFrom, outputTo);
```